# Нужна помощь с скриптом подсчета эффективности по словам

Tags: php, mysql

Пишу аналитику по словам в системе, удалось подсчитать количество заходов по словам. Но есть пару проблем:

1) Нужно отбрасывать / в конце слова, например есть статистика по слову новогодняя елка и новогодняя елка/ нужно подсчитать их в месте и вывести. Как это учесть при выборке?

2) Как в базе подсчитать количество лидов, которые попали по этим словам. При посещении посетителю подставляется hash_person, он записывает с данными utm меток в базу stat, когда клиент оставляет заявку hash_person записывается с контактными данными в базу lids. Как вывести в таблицу количество лидов например по слову "новогодняя елка"?

Скрин того что получилось: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Код:

```
$source_p = mysql_query("                               
SELECT
`utm_term`, COUNT(`utm_term`) AS `cnt`
FROM 
`stat`
WHERE
 id_cabinet = '$id_cabinet' $filtr_date
GROUP BY 
`utm_term`");
if (mysql_num_rows($source_p) > 0) {

while ($source_c = mysql_fetch_array($source_p)) {

if ($source_c['utm_term'] !== '') {
$title_source = $source_c['utm_term'];
} else {
$title_source = "Нет данных";
}
// попытка подсчитать количество лидов по фразе                                 
$result_stat_leads = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stat WHERE utm_term = '".$source_c['utm_term']."'" ,$db);

while ($stat_leads = mysql_fetch_array($result_stat_leads)) {

$result_count_leads = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM lids WHERE hash_person = '".$stat_leads['hash_person']."'" ,$db);

while ($count_stat_leads = mysql_fetch_array($result_count_leads)) {
    $count_leads = ""; // количество лидов                                          
}

}



$count_view = $source_c['cnt']; // количество заходов на сайт по фразе

echo "Слово: $title_source | Лидов: $count_leads";

}
```

Структура таблиц:

```
--
-- Структура таблицы `lids`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `lids` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_cabinet` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_staff` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `hash_person` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `name` text NOT NULL,
  `tel` text NOT NULL,
  `email` text NOT NULL,
  `information` text NOT NULL,
  `comment` text NOT NULL,
  `address` text NOT NULL,
  `note` text NOT NULL,
  `datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_last_edit` datetime NOT NULL,
  `source` text NOT NULL,
  `add_vid` text NOT NULL,
  `idform` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `id_type` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `hash` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `status_old` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `delete_status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status_view` int(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251 AUTO_INCREMENT=35997 ;

--
-- Структура таблицы `stat`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stat` (
  `id` int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_cabinet` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `hash_person` varchar(35) NOT NULL COMMENT 'id зашедшего на сайт',
  `number_visit` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Номер визита',
  `id_lead` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `referrer_site` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `site_project` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `page_site_project` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `title_page` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `region` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `utm_source` text NOT NULL COMMENT 'обозначает источник рекламного трафика (Google, Яндекс, Email, Blog)',
  `utm_medium` text NOT NULL COMMENT 'определяет тип маркетингового канала (PPC, КМС, ретаргетинг, рассылка, пост)',
  `utm_campaign` text NOT NULL COMMENT 'соответствует названию маркетинговой кампании или рекламному объявлению или местоположению баннера',
  `utm_term` text NOT NULL COMMENT 'параметр, содержащий в себе ключевое слово PPC кампании',
  `utm_content` text NOT NULL COMMENT 'отображает контент объявления, что помогает различать разные рекламные объявления, содержащие одно и то же ключевое слово. ',
  `utm_block` text NOT NULL COMMENT 'Тип площадки: premium – спецразмещение other – блок внизу none – блок не на поиске Яндекса',
  `utm_position` text NOT NULL COMMENT 'Позиция в рекламном блоке',
  `utm_ad` text NOT NULL COMMENT 'Номер (ID) объявления',
  `utm_phrase` text NOT NULL COMMENT 'Номер (ID) ключевой фразы',
  `yclid` varchar(100) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Идентификатор яндекса',
  `datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251 AUTO_INCREMENT=251420 ;
```

Я запутался и не понимаю как дальше делать =/

Comment: Не понятно, зачем делать в php `select *` для подсчета количеств. практически любую аналитику можно собрать единым sql зпрососм. Но для ответа на ваш вопрос надо знать структуру базы и желательно примеры данных в таблицах

Comment: тут надо из базы stat вытащить все ключевики, посчитать сколько переходов по ним на сайт клиента, далее посчитать сколько лидов пришло по каждому из ключевиков. В таблице stat есть столбец hash_person (идентификатор посетителя), если посетитель отправляет заявку, то hash_person записывается в базу вместе с контактами посетителя. Вот надо просто все это вывести, а как это сделать не могу понять...

Comment: @maki, пробовал так одним запросом `$query_firms = mysql_query("select st1.id, st1.utm_term, st1.hash_person, COUNT('l'.'id') AS 'count_keyword_leads', ('st1'.'id') AS 'count_view_keyword'
          from stat st1
          left join stat st2 on st2.utm_term = st1.utm_term and st2.id_cabinet = $id_cabinet 
          left join lids l on st2.hash_person = l.status and l.id_cabinet = $id_cabinet $filtr_date $filtr_groupleads and l.delete_status = '0'
          where 
           st1.id_cabinet = $id_cabinet
          group by 
           st1.utm_term
          order by 
           st1.utm_term");`

Comment: Ну вот прямо так вы точно правильно не посчитаете. Не понятно например зачем stat клеится сам к себе. На ваш вопрос невозможно верно ответить не имея под рукой тестовой базы с вашей структорой и несколькими строками данных. сделали бы фидл что ли на http://sqlfiddle.com/ и ссылку скинули. Или подходящий sql на создание базы в текст вопроса добавили

Comment: А что касается первого вопроса, то можно например просто '/' убрать из строк select REPLACE(word,'/',''),count(1) from table group by REPLACE(word,'/','')

Comment: @maki добавил структуры таблиц

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Решил проблему по совету @mike поставив индексы к обрабатываемым столбцам. Ну и сам запрос собственно улучшил и усложнил.

```
select ST.utm_term, ST.hash_person, COUNT(ST.utm_term) AS `stat_count`, count(distinct L.id) AS `lids_count`, count(distinct LL.id) AS `clients_count`
FROM stat ST
left join lids L on L.hash_person=ST.hash_person and L.id_cabinet = '$id_cabinet' $filtr_date_l and L.delete_status='0'
left join leads_sort LS on LS.id_cabinet = $id_cabinet and LS.url = 'done'
left join status S on LS.id_parameter = S.leadssort and S.id_cabinet = $id_cabinet
left join lids LL on S.id = LL.status and LL.hash_person = ST.hash_person and L.id_cabinet = '$id_cabinet' $filtr_date_ll and LL.delete_status = '0'
WHERE ST.id_cabinet=$id_cabinet $filtr_date_st
GROUP BY 
`utm_term`
ORDER BY 
`clients_count`
DESC
```

И так, запрос считает 1е- сколько посетителей по данному ключевику, 2е - считает количество лидов по ключевику, 3е - считает сколько клиентов (в деньги) по определенному ключу.

Спасибо всем кто помог.

Answer (score 3):

Информации в вопросе все еще мало. Например, совершенно не ясно, что такое `id_cabinet` и почему в php скрипте вы его учитываете только при вычислении общего количества по ключевому слову, а при подсчете lid для данного слова вы его не учитываете. Хотя в приведенном в комментариях запросе `id_cabinet` проверяется на равенство везде. Исхожу из того, что его все таки надо применять ко всем таблицам. И в php у вас еще подразумевается наличие еще каких то фильтров, которые как я понимаю могут сказаться на количестве лидов, но не посещений.

```
select REPLACE(utm_term,'/','') word,
       count(distinct ST.id) stat_count,
       count(distinct ST.hash_person) person_stat_count,
       count(distinct L.id) lids_count,
       count(distinct L.hash_person) lids_person
  from stat ST
  left join lids L on L.hash_person=ST.hash_person and L.id_cabinet=0 and L.delete_status=0
 where ST.id_cabinet=0
 group by REPLACE(utm_term,'/','')
```

Исходя из доступной информации я решил, что подзапросы тут не нужны и подсчет уникальных значений разных полей даст требуемый результат. `stat_count` - общее кол-во записей в stat по данному слову, `person_stat_count` кол-во уникальных посетителей на слово, `lids_count` - кол-во заказов от людей, кто попадался в статистике по данному слову, `lids_person` - уникальные покупатели (без учета нескольких заказов от одного hash_person)

Но что то мне подсказывает, что вы считаете погоду в америке. Хотя смотря как у вас считается `hash_person`. Предположим я попадал к вам на сайт несколько раз, по разным ключевым словам, и в конце концов сделал 1 заказ. В таком случае `lids` будет засчитан для всех ключевых слов где я был.

Comment: id_cabinet - это id проекта по сути (сайта) клиента.  Можно поинтересоваться что такое 'word'?  Кстати, почему-то скрипт не работает, грузит долго что-то =/

Comment: У меня просто нет привычки писать AS, поэтому word это просто имя выводимой колонки, можно убрать в принципе, вам же имена не нужны я так думаю. по поводу "долго грузит" - конечно стоит посмотреть план выполнения. думаю индекс по полю hash_person не помешал бы если записей много

Comment: hash_person примерно так выглядит 980264.1482495774522. как вам показать это план выполнения?

Comment: Вы извините меня конечно за тупизм. Могу чего-то не знать...

Comment: а так вообще просто белый экран показывает ничего не выводит =(

Comment: А вы запрос в чем выполняете ? Может просто данных подходящих нет, по заданному cabinet_id.

Comment: Все есть =) более 10000 записей в базе именно с тем id_cabinet с которым я эксперементирую

Comment: А белый экран то вам какое средство показывает ? Например у меня mysql workbench ошибки показывать не хочет, приходится при ошибках тестировать запрос просто в консоли, в mysql. И индекс на поле hash_person при таком кол-ве записей очень даже нужен.

Comment: а что за индекс то? я немного не понял

Comment: белый экран показывает в браузере

Comment: Индекс - для быстрого поиска. по хорошему в stat можно просто по id_cabinet, в lids наверное сходу по двум полям построить один (id_cabinet,hash_person). http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/MySQL_indexes.html

Comment: Ну в браузере ... я же не знаю что ваш скрипт там творит. вы сам запрос протестируйте в mysql ну или в phpmyadmin или в чем вы там запросы обычно проверяете. А потом, когда видите, что запрос рабочий - переносите его в php-скрипт, подставляете переменные, отлаживаете сам скрипт

Comment: Хотя по id_cabinet может и не стоит индекс в stat делать, может статься что по индексу будет дольше выбирать, раз у вас там по одному id_cabinet чуть ли не половина всего объема таблицы ...

Comment: таблица где-то 280.000 строк, из них 10.000 по id_cabinet=282

Comment: попробовал щас сделать запрос в базе чет пишет "загружается" уже минут 5 так

Comment: главное странно, щас вообще phpmyadmin из-за запроса затупила...

Comment: Да тяжелый он слишком. думаете ему легко искать каждый hash_person полным перебором таблицы из 200к записей. индексы постройте, план выполнения посмотрите. Ну и дальше надо думать, может поход менять к запросу может еще что доделать. Мне на моих 10 тестовых записях что с ним еще делать бесполезно.

Comment: Поля выбираемые в запросе только те оставьте, которые действительно нужны, я же все перечислил что бы показать как что выбирается. А каждый distinct его наверное тормозит

Comment: как я понял чтобы создать индекс достаточно нажать Индекс напротив поля, так? https://gyazo.com/4b94837fe13c4a332ca86b04e7465f8b

Comment: создал я индексы, чего с ними делать то?

Comment: Ничего не делать. запросы по идее должны быстрее выполняться. можно в плане выполнения конечно глянуть использует ли он индексы. Правда я все равно не знаю как это в планах MySQL выглядит.

Comment: что даже запрос менять не надо никак, тупо нажать создать индекс по столбцам hash_person и id_cabinet и все и просто попробовать запустить заново...

Comment: ну да оптимизатор сам старается выбрать оптимальный путь